# What's the way to just calculate a variable when it's called in a function?

Tags: javascript

It's very difficult to ask this question to explain my real problem, but i try it here. I have a function, inside of it are some variables, and inside the function is another function, which is an always changing function. This may be complicated for first look, but let me explain in this code:

```
var a, b, x;

function myF(y, fn) {
  x = y;
  a = x * 2;
  b = x * 3;
  //in my real code a and b are much complicated, and there are 10 variables,
  //and almost all of them are always changing (depending on scroll)
  //i need them to be defined, but i don't always use them
  //how which is used depends on the fn.
  return fn();
}

function innerOne() {
  return a * x;
}

function innerTwo() {
  return b * x;
}

myF(3, innerOne);
//when this function called, the b is also calculated, but never used
myF(6, innerTwo);
//same situation, but with a
```

I want to improve my code's performance, by not calculating actually unnecesarry variables, so i want to know if are there a way to check the elements used by `fn()`, and just calculate those.

My original code looks like [this](https://codepen.io/Grsz/pen/jzOLbG.js)

Comment: You do know that you can put `var` statements inside functions, right?

Comment: I would suggest looking into functional programming. It's a different way of thinking about variables and functions. Basically, instead of using global variables, you'd pass the output of one function to the next.

Comment: Have a look at this article: https://crockford.com/javascript/private.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> i want to know if are there a way to check the elements used by fn(), and just calculate those.

No. You cannot tell which variables a function will access until you've run the function, this is a specialization of the [halting problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Halting_problem).

You could come close, by (for example) using `toString` on the function to retrieve its source code and performing static analysis, but even then you cannot tell for sure what variables it will access conditionally without actually executing the code.

This isn't really a problem in JavaScript or most other languages. The simple solution here is to rethink have you've architected your code so that the computations are done on demand, instead of precomputing them.